# CSS animation smooth with variable width

Tags: css, animation

I was wondering how to make something like [THIS GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3JDF0y10q4IYacVi/giphy.gif) in CSS and anime.js. I want it to be smooth, starting from a word with only consonants and then smoothly opening up space to allow a vowel to appear, one (or all) at a time.

The clue is that the word is centered, no mattre how long it is or how many letters is contains. When you add a letter (with animation) it should stay centered and smoothly open up space to fade in the next letter.

I am no expert at all and I don't even know how to start this. Except for moving every letter separately 1 px at a time, but that would be hours of work and not reusable for other words (for example `i` is smaller then `w` or `s`)

Is this even possible in css? 
Thanks your input or advice in advance.

Comment: Why downvote and not let me know why? This helps no one..

Comment: Probably because you have not given us any clue as to what you've already attempted. You do not have to be _an expert_ to get started on this, but there is a level of expectation from the community that you make an effort before you ask if something is possible. We also cannot help you debug your efforts if you do not provide us with code (preferably in a snippet within your answer), nor is SO a code-writing service. Read [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on that. (Note: I'm not the downvoter, in case you were wondering).

Comment: @chazsolo Thing is I have no clue how to start, not even in the slightest, except pixel by pixel. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with fixed space letters then you can do it in pure CSS: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsmdpjy9/49/).

```
<p>
  <span>N</span>
  <span class="vowel">i</span>
  <span>c</span>
  <span class="vowel">o</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span class="vowel">a</span>
  <span>s</span>
</p>
<style>
  p span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:0.7em;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .vowel {
    opacity:0;
    width:0em;
    animation:enter 0.6s 0.4s forwards;
  }
  .vowel ~ .vowel {
    animation-delay:0.6s;
  }
  .vowel ~ .vowel ~ .vowel {
    animation-delay:0.9s;
  }

  @keyframes enter {
    0% { width:0; opacity:0; }
    49% {opacity:0;}
    50% {opacity:1;}
    100% { width:0.7em; opacity:1;}
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am trying to play with this fiddle to find a solution for the fixed width! This is a great start